# Showing Listview from JSON using AsynTask

Tags: android, json, listview

I got some problem to show `listview` from `JSON` using `asyntask`. I want to data showing under specific `radiobutton` clicked, but DDMS result shows `"Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"`.

**ListResult.java**

```
public class ListResult extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
String paramString;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> busList; 
RadioButton rbSUN;
RadioButton rbFRI;
RadioButton rbSAT;
ListView lv;
private int success;
private static String url_insert_new = "http://10.0.2.2/onlineLibrary/getallbus.php";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_IDIOMS = "idioms";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_TIME = "time";
private static final String TAG_STATUS = "status";  
JSONArray idioms = null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_result);
    busList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();  
    lv = getListView();
    rbSUN = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioSUN);
    rbFRI = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioFRI);
    rbSAT = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioSAT);
    rbSUN.setOnClickListener(this);
    rbFRI.setOnClickListener(this);
    rbSAT.setOnClickListener(this);   
    new InsertNewIdiom().execute();
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId()==R.id.radioSUN){
        new InsertNewIdiom().execute();
        if (success==1){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New item saved...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New item FAILED to saved...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        paramString="SUN";
    }    
    if (v.getId()==R.id.radioFRI){
        new InsertNewIdiom().execute();
        if (success==1){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New item saved...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New item FAILED to saved...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        paramString="FRI";
    }
    if (v.getId()==R.id.radioSAT){
        new InsertNewIdiom().execute();
        if (success==1){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New item saved...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New item FAILED to saved...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        paramString="SAT";
    } 
}
class InsertNewIdiom extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListResult.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("time", TAG_TIME));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status", TAG_STATUS));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_insert_new,
                "GET", params);
        Log.d("Insert New item Response", json.toString());
        try {
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                  idioms = json.getJSONArray(TAG_IDIOMS);
                  for (int i = 0; i < idioms.length(); i++) {
                      JSONObject c = idioms.getJSONObject(i);
                      String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                      String time = c.getString(TAG_TIME);
                      String status = c.getString(TAG_STATUS);
                      HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                      map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                      map.put(TAG_TIME, time);
                      map.put(TAG_STATUS, status);
                      busList.add(map);
                  }               
            } else {
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
       // pDialog.dismiss();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        ListResult.this, busList,
                        R.layout.list_view, new String[] 
{ TAG_ID,   TAG_TIME, TAG_STATUS},
                        new int[] { R.id.id, R.id.time, R.id.status});
               setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

**JsonParser.java**

```
public class JSONParser {
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";
public JSONParser() {

}
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {
    try {
        if(method == "POST"){
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    return jObj;

 }

 }
```

**activity_list_result.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android=
   "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

  <ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center" 

    >

  <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"      
   android:orientation="vertical" 

   >
  <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"      
   android:orientation="vertical" 
   android:background="#B3E5FC"
   >
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textGranular"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="BUS Schedule:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
    android:textColor="#0000ff"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    />

   <HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioSUN"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Sunday-Thursday" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioFRI"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
            android:text="Friday" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioSAT"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Saturnday" />


      </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
       </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="396dp" >
    </ListView>

       </LinearLayout>  
  </LinearLayout>    
   </ScrollView>

   </LinearLayout>
```

**list_view.xlm**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:weightSum="6"
    >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView2"
         android:layout_width="57dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:padding="2dp"
         android:text="Time:"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
         android:textColor="#000"
         android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

       </LinearLayout>


 <!-- Entry data display -->
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:weightSum="6"
    >       
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView3"
         android:layout_width="57dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:padding="2dp"
         android:text="Status:"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
         android:textColor="#000"
         android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="14sp" />       
       </LinearLayout> 
</LinearLayout>
```

**getallbus.php**

```
  <?php
  $response=array();
  $paramString=$_REQUEST[''];

  require_once __DIR__.'/db_connect.php';
  $db=new DB_CONNECT();
  $sql="SELECT * FROM getbus WHERE day='$paramString'";

  $result=mysql_query($sql);

   if(!empty($result))
  {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        $response['idioms']=array();
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $book=array();
            $book['day']=$row['day'];
            $book['time']=$row['time'];
            $book['status']=$row['status'];

            array_push($response['idioms'], $book);
        }
        $response['success']=1;
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else {
        $response['success']=0;
        $response['message']='No data found';

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
  }
 ?>
```

**Logcat**

```
02-07 14:37:09.761: E/JSON Parser(1195): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject 
02-07 14:37:19.091: E/JSON Parser(1195): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Comment: Please add logcat error trace and the JSON.

Comment: here is my logcat error message

Comment: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: There is a `Html` tag `<br/>` in your json. Fix your json data.

Comment: here is my database .sql file and php file is in code , i can't fix JSON data problem @Rohit5k2  -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.5.2.2
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Server version: 5.5.27
-- PHP Version: 5.4.7
--
-- Database: `hstu`
-- Table structure for table `getbus`
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `getbus` (
  `day` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `time` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) 
-- Dumping data for table `getbus`
INSERT INTO `getbus` (`day`, `time`, `status`) VALUES
('SUN', '6:40 am', 'General (1)'),
('SUN', '7:oo am', 'Student (2)');

Comment: Try to log your json in the parser class (before parsing it). See what you are getting.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\onlineLibrary\getallbus.php on line 3,here line 3 is  $paramString=$_REQUEST[''];

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP file is failing, and in turn, the Exception that is shown is being passed (as HTML data, since it's a PHP file) back to your application, which isn't checking for a success code.  Since your app is just taking the data and running with it, it's trying to parse that exception from your PHP file as JSON, which, obviously, won't work.  You need to verify, in your PHP file, that no exceptions are thrown and that it gives a valid JSON response.

As far as your PHP exception goes, you're trying to access an array index in `$_REQUEST` that doesn't exist, as you're passing an empty string to the `[]`.  This is causing your PHP file to fail. When PHP throws an exception, it gives a default response (as HTML) describing the error, and your app is trying to parse it as JSON, failing miserably.

So if you're sending the request to the PHP file as

```
getallbus.php?requestParam=[yourRequestParam] // aka `GET`
```

then you would use

```
$paramString = $_GET['requestParam'];
```

If you're sending the request as a `POST`, you would use,

```
$paramString = $_POST['requestParam'];
```

This way, PHP shouldn't throw an exception, as long as there actually is an index called 'requestParam.' Hope this helps.